# Android RdioGroup clearCheck conflict with setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-group

I'm trying to take an action when a radio button clicked:

```
  dataBinding.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup: RadioGroup, i: Int ->
       
if( radioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId != -1){
        checkAnswer(i)
       }
    }
```

inside another function there is a `clearCheck` to clear radio button .
the issue is that every time `clearCheck` is called, the listener `setOnCheckedChangeListener` also called.

is there any way to run the listener to get run when a radio button is selected and not when it is cleared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
 * <p>Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the checked
 * radio button changed in this group.</p>
 */
public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    /**
     * <p>Called when the checked radio button has changed. When the
     * selection is cleared, checkedId is -1.</p>
     *
     * @param group the group in which the checked radio button has changed
     * @param checkedId the unique identifier of the newly checked radio button
     */
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId);
}
```

When you call `clearCheck()` method on the RadioGroup, if there is a RadioButton is checked, it will set the state of this view to unchecked, then notify the app about the state of a radio button changed by calling `onCheckedChanged()` method of the instance that you pass into `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method.

This explains why in your app, if users select a wrong answer, it will call `onCheckedChange()` twice. The former is when the state change from unchecked to checked, the latter is when the state change from checked to unchecked via `clearCheck()`. This is the expected behavior.

**Solution:** Clear the OnCheckedChangeListener before calling `clearCheck()` method, then set it after calling `clearCheck()` method.

```
// Declare this variable
private val onCheckedChangeListener = object : RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    override fun onCheckedChanged(group: RadioGroup?, checkedId: Int) {
        if (checkedId != -1) {
            checkAnswer(checkedId)
        }
    }
}

// Calling this line once, inside onCreate() of Activity 
// or onCreateView() of Fragment for example
dataBinding.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener)

private fun checkAnswer(checkedId: Int) {
    // Your logic to check answer here
    // ...

    // If the answer is wrong, just clear check
    dataBinding.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
    dataBinding.radioGroup.clearCheck()
    dataBinding.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener)
}
```