# Whne i call this radiogroupId.clearCheck() this method recall radiogroup click listener

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

**Details:** I have 2 radio groups with some radio buttons.

**What i want:** User only select one radio button from 2 groups.

**What i have done:**

```
 rgOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            try {
                val checkedRadioButtonId: Int = rgOne.checkedRadioButtonId
                if (checkedRadioButtonId != null) {
                    oneItem = oneList[checkedRadioButtonId]
                    healthy = oneItem.code!!
                    AppGlobal.displayShortToast(
                        this, "You selected: " + oneItem.title
                    )
                    if (rgTwo.checkedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                       rgTwo.clearCheck()

                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }


        })

        
        rgTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
            try {
                val checkedRadioButtonId: Int = rgTwo.checkedRadioButtonId
                if (checkedRadioButtonId != null) {
                    twoItem = twoList[checkedRadioButtonId]
                    unhealthy = twoItem.code!!
                    AppGlobal.displayShortToast(
                        this, "You selected: " + twoItem.title
                    )
                    if (rgOne.checkedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                     rgOne.clearCheck()

                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        })
```

**Facing the issue:** When i call this rgOne.clearCheck() OR rgTwo.clearCheck() ,call whole radio group clicked listener agin and uncheck what i checked. working perfect for first time like when nothig is selected.

*What is wrong with this code and what i need to change.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calling this line once, inside onCreate() of Activity or onCreateView() of Fragment:**

```
   rgOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener)
   rgTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener)
```

**Declare this variable:**

```
private val onCheckedChangeListener =  
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
        if (group!!.id == R.id.rgOne) {
            try {
                AppLog.e("Call healthy")
                val checkedRadioButtonId: Int = rgOne.checkedRadioButtonId
                if (checkedRadioButtonId != null) {
              
                    if (rgTwo.checkedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                        resetRadioGroup(rgTwo)
                        
                    }


                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        } else {
            try {
                AppLog.e("Call Unhealthy")
                val checkedRadioButtonId: Int = rgTwo.checkedRadioButtonId
                if (checkedRadioButtonId != null) {
                   
                    if (rgOne.checkedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                        resetRadioGroup(rgOne)
                        
                    }


                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }

    }
```

**Function for reset radiogroup:**

```
fun resetRadioGroup(rgType: RadioGroup) {
    rgType.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
    rgType.clearCheck()
    rgType.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener)
}
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64602672/5995648)